# understanding click(),change() and inputs scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand scope as far as inputs and clicks or checks are concerned. I am working on a project and what I am trying to do is. Ask if they work out a lot, they will answer yes or no. then I will ask them 3 question either way. I will ask how much they can bench, how much they can squat, how much they can curl. I have this part set up I will give them feedback based on what they input. What I am trying to do is add a check box to it for them to select if they are male or female. I think I should do it something like this

```
function one() {
    a = 100;
    b = 200;
    c = 300;
    return two();

    function two() {
        a += a;
        b += b;
        c += c;
        return three();

        function three() {
            a += 1;
            b += 1;
            c += 1;
            return four();

            function four() {
                console.log(a, b, c);
            }
        }
    }
}
one()
```

I guess my question is how would I do this with click and checks and inputs. It seems no matter where I add the check box to what I have, it will not work for some reason. Either there will be a issue with the first question... Do you work out a lot? a the question will not be there. Or I will get a post era. I have a fiddle below. If someone would tell me how to make it work...or even better show me it working, I will be very thankful. I think this would help a lot of people out. I have seen a lot of good answers to this question on here, but no working examples. I think the most helpful thing for some people, is a working example they can see, I know it is for me.

ps in my fiddle i am recycling the same inputs for the questions i'm asking. Whether they work out or not, i would like to do it properly, but not my main issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/vicky1212/G24aQ/10/

Comment: It is difficult to help when we have a lot to assume. Will be lot better if you can rephrase the question and point out the exact problems you are trying to solve

Comment: What do you want to understand exactly, how to add a (bind,action) to an specific control (button, select, etc)?? We can help you if you ask exactly what you want...

Comment: I put the set up and what i am trying to do in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/vicky1212/MVCGS/

Comment: I'm trying to take in a few inputs from a user and use them, sorry i can't really explain it more then that. In my fiddle after the first question when the next 3 come up, they are set up to answer with a number 1-10, then i am adding them and giving them a message back. i would like to be able to add a check box in there, but i don't know how.

Comment: @nahum they would pick owner or not...then answer the questions like now, and i want to add a check box with male or female. then they will hit go. you can use what i have now but just add a check box with male female, and if it's male. when i give them the message back like i am instead of it saying "That's bad, should be higher..." like it does now...if they checked male or female and it says "Sr or miss That's bad, should be higher..." that is good enough. I am just trying to get a check box to work with what i have now.

Comment: @user2537145 It appears you want a survey, where questions are displayed one at a time. See my answer for a simple example of such a survey. The posted code can just be copied/pasted into a single document and it will run. [See the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPbvK/) for an immediate example.

Comment: @gibberish Super helpful! I know i'm not supposed  to thank you but I have to!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some explanation with the code..

```
$('.myOptions').change(function () {
    // Remove the active class
    $('.list').removeClass('active');
    // Add the active class
    // this.value holds the current value that is selected
    // No need to use filter 
    $('.' + this.value).addClass('active');
});

$('#butt').click(function () {
    // Better to have Lesser variables ,  
    var active = $('.list.active'),
        $boxOne = active.find('.box1'),
        $boxTwo = active.find('.box2'),
        $boxThree = active.find('.box3'),
        $output = $('#output'),
        total = (parseInt($boxOne.val(), 10) + parseInt($boxTwo.val(), 10) + parseInt($boxThree.val(), 10)),
        msg = '';

    $output.addClass('error');
    var dropdownValue = $('.myOptions').val(),
        // you need to select the inputs specifically
        // you were trying to access it using $('input') that gives the list of all the inputs
        // on your page.. So you need to be more specific
        $genderRadio = $('input[name=gender]');
    // If dropdown is empty show some message
    if (dropdownValue === '') {
        msg = 'Please select an option....';
    } else if (isNaN(total)) {
        msg = 'Input three numbers, please...';
    } // If gender is not selected show a specific message
    else if ($genderRadio.filter(':checked').length === 0) {
        msg = 'Please select your gender....';
    } else {
        // If it comes to this statemenet it means there is no error
        // remove the error class
        $output.removeClass('error');
        if (total < 14) {
            msg = "That's bad, should be higher...";
        } else if (total > 15) {
            msg = "That's bad, should be lower...";
        } else {
            msg = "You got it... Nice work.";
        }

        var genderPrefix = $genderRadio.filter(':checked').val() === 'Male' ? 'Sir..' : 'Miss..';
        msg = genderPrefix + msg;
    }

    $output.text(msg);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVCGS/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I will give an little introduction to `javascript` pattern with my example. you can read about them in http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ is not a easy reading but when you are ready you will understand pretty much about how to organize you javascript code with that book.

meanwhile I can advise you to read about how to code forms with good practices at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/20-html-forms-best-practices-for-beginners/

Ok beside that here are the working example about how to work with click and forms http://jsfiddle.net/ncubica/BQaYz/

HTML

```
<label><input type="Radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" /> male</label>
<label><input type="Radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />female</label>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" />
<input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="lastname" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="store" />
```

javascript

```
var survey = (function(_module){
    var modulename = _module;
    var user = {};
    /*private methods*/

    function init(){
        observers();
    }

    function observers(){
        $(document).on("click","#submit", survey.store)
    }

    /*public methods*/
    $r = {}

    $r.store = function(){
        user.name = $("#name").val();
        user.lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        user.gender = $("input:radio[name=gender]:checked").val();
        survey.toString();
    }

    $r.toString = function(){
        var genderStr = (user.gender == "male") ? "Man" : "Girl";
        alert(user.name + " " + user.lastname + " is " + genderStr);
    }

    $r.init = function(){
        init();
    }

    return $r;
})("survey")

survey.init();
```

Ok, I know at first look a little "big" code but is really simple, in javascript a variable can take any kind of form from a function to a normal string.

here we are working with `anonymous functions` to create a module will help us to work more clear and structure, this variable will have 2 kind of methods and variable, public and privates.

for make a method public we have to return the methods in an object after we finish to run the code this is why exist the `$r` variable which is an object who have function by properties, and at the end of the code you return it doing `return $r` with this pattern now you can easily can navigate throw methods and catch events like click, change, etc....

you only should have to add this event to the method `observers` create a private or public function which will be activate after the event an you are done.

Read the code and if you have any further question you can ask me anything. I try to solve you problem and structure you code.

best good luck

Comment: @Sushanth exactly what i was asking!!! & nahum thank you both very much. Was starting to think no one ever used a check box and drop down together to ask a few questions lol. But seriously I have seen a ton of good info one here alone about this but not a working example, it's always everything by it's self, i think this will be super helpful for newer people to see a working example...that they can add to or take from.

Comment: @user237145 Please if this work for you, we only asked you upvoted for our answer our marked as right answer. Please take the time to do this. I glad this examples help you...

Comment: wish i could up vote up both, when i get some points, i will come back to this question to do it!

Comment: hahaha no worry man have a good day... i will help you with some point in you question..

Comment: I tried to use the examples and modify it a little. And not going to well lol, am I able to do what I am trying to do here in this fiddle? I used Sushanth -- example and tried to make it where the values where not tied to box1, box2 and box3 when you picked owner or non-owner, they each had there own values. My goal was to give back different feed back and value answers different between the 2, and I added another output to do it.    http://jsfiddle.net/7xM2f/1/

Comment: sorry was in a rush this one is cleaner but still does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/7xM2f/11/

Answer (score 0):

[[Here is below answer as a jsFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/mPbvK/)

This answer is intended as a starter. I tried to write it at a beginner level, so that you can customize it for yourself. Hopefully, this simple example can give you a starting place. I used the example of a training gym asking some basic questions of their users.

My approach was to create an empty DIV, called `#ques`, where all Questions and output will be displayed, and a hidden `<form>` containing hidden fields that will store the responses.

I created a counter, `cnt`, which is incremented after each question.

There is a function called `ask_next_ques()` that takes the parameter `cnt`. Depending on where we are in the survey, it asks the next question (eg. when cnt==3 it asks the third question).

Unfortunately, javascript insists that all strings be on one line. Therefore, I built the html like this:

```
var qq = '
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li>
            What can you curl?<br />
            <input type="text" id="curl"> Kg
        </li>
        <li>
            What can you bench?<br />
            <input type="text" id="bench"> Kg
        </li>
        <li>
            What can you lift?<br />
            <input type="text" id="lift"> Kg
            <input type="button" id="cbl_btn" value="Go">
        </li>
    </ul>
';
```

and then re-arranged it onto one line, like this:

```
var qq = '<ul style="list-style:none"><li>What can you curl?<br /><input type="text" id="curl"> Kg</li><li>What can you bench?<br /><input type="text" id="bench"> Kg</li><li>What can you lift?<br /><input type="text" id="lift"> Kg<input type="button" id="cbl_btn" value="Go"></li></ul>';
```

Much more difficult to read that way, but that's how javascript wants things.

As each question is answered, the responses are read by javascript/jQuery and then saved into hidden fields inside the `<form>` structure.

When all questions have been asked, you can just POST the form to another (PHP?) file for processing (storage in a MySQL database?), or email the answers to yourself, or re-display them to the user, or... I chose to display the answers in a lightbox.

Here is all the code. Just copy/paste it into a single HTML or PHP file, and run.

SURVEY.PHP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /><!--Lightbox-->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><!--Lightbox-->

        <style>
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Declare vars outside document.ready() so they can be accessed globally
            var ctr = 1;
            var mf = '';
            var pl = '';

            $(document).ready(function() {

                ask_next_ques(ctr);

                /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
                $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
                    //Note: var mf must be initialized above (outside document.ready() ) so can be used in below fn ask_next_ques()
                    mf = $('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val();
                    $('#hgender').val(mf);
                    ctr++;
                    ask_next_ques(ctr);
                });
                /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
                $(document).on('click', "#cbl_btn", function() {
                    var cc = $("#curl").val();
                    var bb = $("#bench").val();
                    var ll = $("#lift").val();

                    //alert('Value of cc: ' +cc+ '   Value of bb: ' +bb+ '     Value of ll: ' + ll);

                    //Check if any one of these fields left empty
                    if (cc.length<1 || bb.length<1 || ll.length<1) {
                        alert("Please complete all fields");
                    }else{
                        $('#hcurl').val(cc);
                        $('#hbench').val(bb);
                        $('#hlift').val(ll);
                        ctr++;
                        ask_next_ques(ctr);
                    }
                });             
                /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
                $(document).on('click', "input:radio[name=plan]", function() {
                    //Note: var pl must be initialized above so can be used in below fn ask_next_ques()
                    pl = $('input:radio[name=plan]:checked').val();
                    $('#hplan').val(pl);
                    ctr++;
                    ask_next_ques(ctr);
                });
                /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

            }); //END $(document).ready()

            function ask_next_ques(ctr) {
                if (ctr==1) {
                    var qq = 'Male: <input value="Male" type="radio" name="gender"><br />Female: <input value="Female" type="radio" name="gender">';
                    $('#ques').html(qq);
                }else if (ctr==2){
                    var qq = '<ul style="list-style:none"><li>What can you curl?<br /><input type="text" id="curl"> Kg</li><li>What can you bench?<br /><input type="text" id="bench"> Kg</li><li>What can you lift?<br /><input type="text" id="lift"> Kg<input type="button" id="cbl_btn" value="Go"></li></ul>';
                    $('#ques').html(qq);
                }else if (ctr==3){
                    var qq = 'Are you an:<br />Owner: <input value="Owner" type="radio" name="plan"><br />Member: <input value="Member" type="radio" name="plan">';
                    $('#ques').html(qq);
                }else if (ctr==4){
                    //All questions have been asked; All responses saved into hidden fields
                    //Can now read all hidden fields and do an AJAX POST into the database, or
                    //Or can simply POST the form to another page for processing.
                    alert("All questions have been asked");

                    var hg = $('#hgender').val();
                    var hc = $('#hcurl').val();
                    var hb = $('#hbench').val();
                    var hl = $('#hlift').val();
                    var hp = $('#hplan').val();
                    qq = 'The values saved into all hidden fields are:<br />Gender: ['+hg+ ']<br />Curl: [' +hc+ ']<br />Bench: [' +hb+ ']<br />Lift: [' +hl+ ']<br />Plan: [' +hp+ ']<br />You can now send these values to a<br />database, or email them to yourself.';
                    $('#ques').html(qq);

                    //We could just leave it here, but to be interesting we'll display the results in a lightbox
                    //To remove all lightbox stuff, just delete the next 8 lines and delete the two lightbox references in the header (for jquery-ui)
                    $('#ques').dialog({
                        autoOpen:true,
                        width: 450,
                        title: "Hidden Field Valuess:",
                        close: function() {
                            alert('Thank you for taking our survey');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>


    <div id="ques"></div>
    <div id="hidden_form">
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="hgender" name="gender">
            <input type="hidden" id="hcurl" name="curl">
            <input type="hidden" id="hbench" name="bench">
            <input type="hidden" id="hlift" name="lift">
            <input type="hidden" id="hplan" name="owner">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```